# Analytical solution of the integral of the secant times a polynomial?

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I have seen this integral in some engineering papers:

$$\int_{R}^{R+l}{x \sec{(Kx)} \left[1-\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)\right]\left[a+b\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)+c\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^2-d\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^3+e\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^4\right]^2   \, dx} $$

where $a,b,c,d,e,l,K>0$, and they claim it can only be solved numerically. However, since they are not mathematicians and neither am I, I wanted to know if there is any possible method for solving this integral in a closed form. It doesn't seem possible, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Even $\int x \sec{x} \, dx$ requires polylogarithms to evaluate, so it's pretty unlikely that the whole expression has a closed form.

Comment: I thought so, but one never knows if there's a math genius lurking around this site, so I'll leave it here just in case ;)